# Swift Array / Dictionary of Range objects

Tags: swift, collections, range

I am trying to store Range objects in a swift collection.

In Obj-C I used to use `[NSValue valueWithRange:r];`

But this option is not available in swift.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, see example below

```
var range1 = Range<Int>(start: 0, end: 100)
var range2 = Range<Int>(start: 100, end: 200)

var array = [range1, range2] // The array type is [Range<Int>]
```

or if you need `NSRange`

```
var range1 = NSRange(location: 0, length: 100)
var range2 = NSRange(location: 100, length: 200)

var array = [range1, range2] // The array type is [_NSRange]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to set the range as [0...3] instead of 0...3